# There are relationships between the tables in the database.Since there are relationships do we need the join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are relationships between the tables in the database.The ER diagram is shown as follows. Since there are relationships between tables, do we need the join?

But the problem is the different queries are giving different results.

I want to find out the name of the Mathematics teacher from the tables.
The relationship is already drawn in the table.
ER diagram:

[image: Relationship]

My query:

```sql
WITH A AS (
    SELECT CLASS_ID,classes.CLASS_NAME,classes.SUBJECT_ID,CLASSES.TEACHER_ID,subjects.SUBJECT_NAME
    FROM CLASSES
    JOIN SUBJECTS ON CLASSES.SUBJECT_ID = SUBJECTS.SUBJECT_ID
)


SELECT distinct(CONCAT(STAFF.FIRST_NAME,' ',STAFF.LAST_NAME)) as 'Maths Teacher',SUBJECT_NAME
FROM A 
JOIN
STAFF
ON
A.TEACHER_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID
WHERE SUBJECT_NAME = 'Mathematics'
```

Which gives me this result

[image: Result 1]

But since there are relationships between the tables later I used this query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,' ', LAST_NAME) as Full_Name, SUBJECT_NAME
FROM STAFF, SUBJECTS
WHERE SUBJECTS.SUBJECT_NAME = 'Mathematics'
GROUP BY CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,' ', LAST_NAME), SUBJECT_NAME;
```

Which gives me this result

[image: Result 2]

I used Excel for the validation of this data which gives me results like this.

[image: Validation].

Which is exactly the same as the 1st query. What I used using join?

So do we require to join two tables even if we have relationship between the tables?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) Your second attempt has an ANSI-89 *CROSS JOIN*; that isn't the same an an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Why do you have `DISTINCT` *and* a `GROUP BY` in the same scope when your `GROUP BY` already returns your data in *distinct* groups? Why are you using a `GROUP BY` when you have *no* aggregation?

Comment: The relationship might exist due to foreign keys and primary keys, but you still need to explicitly define the join condition to determine how the tables should be joined and which columns should be matched.

Comment: You can join 2 tables using any join criteria you want, not just FK relationships.

Comment: The relations are there to ensure that no invalid data can be entered in both tables. But that has nothing to do how you select the data to show on your screen, there you will have to use joins.